# Azure Data Factory, Copy Data, Teradata ODBC , dateTime timestamp mapping

Tags: timestamp, odbc, teradata, azure-data-factory

We're implementing a ADF copy activity of Azure Sql Server to on prem Teradata with the ODBC connector.
We cant make the mapping work for a DateTime > Timestamp6 column and gets various errors when testing. (due to changing the source format)
The source query has been cast/converted to various formats into an intermediate Blob File.

The cast/converts has been:

```
* convert(varchar(26), EventUtcTimeStamp,121) EventUtcTimeStamp //"2020-11-03 12:01:21.928294"
* convert(varchar(19), EventUtcTimeStamp,121) EventUtcTimeStamp //"2020-11-03 12:01:21"
* cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', eventUtcTimeStamp) as bigint) * 1000 eventUtcTimeStamp //1604404881000
```

The Blob File is the source for the second Copy activity where the target is the teradata table. This generates various ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure's .

We suspect the cause to be the sink mapping to teradata, since it cant be changed from DateTime.
The blob file looks ok.
Any one encountered this and know how to tweak it to work, if possible at all?

[Copy Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omayG.png)

[Sink Mapping Teradata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vv9p.png)

Comment: Your first example certainly looks like a timestamp(6).  What happens if you try to move it to a varchar column on teradata, what does it look like?

Comment: Moving it to a varchar column works just fine, its only the timeStamp that fails.

Comment: And just to add how it looks in a teradata varchar column: '2020-03-09 10:27:04.143333'

Comment: Since you applied CONVERT on the source side, shouldn't the sink mapping describe the field in the intermediate Blob File as a string rather than a DateTime?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to insert that into a timestamp(6) field?  @Fred, will Teradata not just do an implicit cast here?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, if you bind a string value to a Date or Timestamp column, the database should do an implicit conversion. In fact, that's how Teradata's own utilities work - they expect the external representation of these types to be a character string. But driver APIs also support binding for other standard types like java.sql.timestamp for JDBC or  SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP and SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP for ODBC.

Comment: I think the problem is within the Data Factory Copy itself.
The error for the "2020-11-03 12:01:21.928294" format is in short:
"ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '2020-03-13 15:11:15.323333' for column name 'InsertedUtcTimeStamp' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'DateTime' (precision:, scale:). Additional info: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Just to clarify, its not possible to change the output sink mapping datatype. Its set as dateTime.

Comment: OK. So the issue is not that Teradata doesn't recognize the format, it's that ADF insists on passing a DateTime/Timestamp value and ADF doesn't recognize the external string format you are using. So either CONVERT to whatever format ADF expects by default or specify an explicit format for the sink mapping schema.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems the ODBC sink with Teradata as a target is not fully supported.

We solved this by creating an ODBC Teradata "staging" table with varchar only columns and some stored procedures/triggers to move it into the real columns.

Quoting from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181894/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-odbc-sink-teradat.html?childToView=193323#answer-193323)

> I got confirmation from Product team that data factory can recognize
> date formats as in this document. Today Teradata as a sink is not
> supported in dataflow yet to convert it as datetime before loading
> into sink. So, unfortunately, this is not possible without
> modification at sink today.
>
> I would recommend to submit an idea in feedback forum that is closely
> monitored by data factory product team and will be implemented in
> future releases.